# Spring security kerberos extension for production use?

Tags: spring-security, kerberos

The Spring Security – Kerberos Extension is listed as version 1.0M2 on the [Spring Source web site](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/extensions/krb/index.html). It was started in 2009.

Why hasn't it made a 1.0 release?

Is it suitable for production use?

If it is not suitable for production use, what is the best alternative to plug into Spring Security?

Answer (score 2):

We use successfully Spring Security Kerberos/SPNego in production since more than one-year, and we are quite happy with it!

However, I can't say why 1.0 is not released.