# Choosing Kerberos (SPNEGO) Java library for web application single sign-on

Tags: java, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego

I'm currently working on implementing enterprise authentication mechanisms in our Java web-application, including single sign-on. Windows networks are what we primary target at, and Kerberos sounds a reasonable choice. Sidenote: as far as I understand, the protocol used in web (HTTP) environment to SSO is SPNEGO, and it's basically a wrapper around Kerberos. Thus it sounds that Kerberos HTTP SSO libraries in fact are using SPNEGO -- correct me if I'm wrong.

As I started investigating this topic, I realized that there's no obvious choice. Let me list those:

1. [Spring security Kerberos/SPNEGO extension](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/extensions/krb/index.html). This was the first I looked at (as we are already using Spring security), but it seems to be stuck at v1.0.0 second milestone few years ago. Only this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040883/spring-security-kerberos-extension-for-production-use) gives slight hope it could be used for production.
2. [WAFFLE - Windows Authentication Functional Framework](http://dblock.github.com/waffle/). Seems to be active and feature-rich. It can be 'plugged' as generic servlet, and also as a [Spring security filter](http://code.dblock.org/single-sign-on-spring-security-negotiate-filter-kerberos-ntlm-wwaffle).
3. [SPNEGO SourceForge](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/index.html). Seems very lightweight, provides HTTP Servlet filter, tutorials are easy to follow.

Are there any particular reasons to choose one option over the other? Are there any other options around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your assumption is correct. You need SPNEGO to perform SSO with HTTP.

1. This can reasonably used in Spring only. If you have it, got for it. We are using it for more that two years. Does its job.
2. This works on Windows only.
3. Uses the same JGSS as the Spring stuff but is framework agnostic. This seems to work very well.

If you are using Tomcat 7, there is already built-in support. I have donated appropriate code. You should speficy what you exactly expect. If you have no expectations but the authentication use either 3 or 1 with Spring.

Comment: Sorry but point "2" is wrong. My Tomcat servers with SPNEGO run on Linux properly. I have also tested authentication from Firefox running on Linux with kerberos client stack configured.

Comment: @YvesMartin, many old answers are invalid by now and I have downvote-attacked for this once. I was true in 2012.

Comment: sorry again but I first deployed in 2009 an Alfresco server on Java 6 with SPNEGO authentication on Linux server with Windows, Linux and Mac clients for EPFL. To sumup, as soon as Java included Kerberos support, it was already platform independant.

Comment: Please reread the question and my answer. The OP refers to three options, I have commented on those three and Waffle runs on Windows only.

Comment: @Michael-O It seems that Spring security Kerberos/SPNEGO extension only supports Spring 4. It doesnt seems to support Spring 3.

Comment: @youcanlearnanything I wouldn't use the extension at all. It is broken security-wise.

Comment: @Michael-O, so the recommended library to use is sourceforge spnego?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything, neither this one. I analyzed both and wasn't happy with these. Implemented by own: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tomcatspnegoad/

Comment: @Michael-O is it applicable for tomcat only?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything, correct since I use Tomcat only at work.

Comment: @Michael-O I am using Struts and Spring 3 based web app.

Comment: You can use my package in Spring Sec too, by wrapping container-managed security. See http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/spring-security.html.