# Java SSO using SPNEGO

Tags: java, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego, waffle

I'm newbie in this topic. I need help to implement the authentication Java SSO for a web application over Tomcat 6.0.29. I have read about SPNEGO and proven the examples helloKDC.java and hello_spnego.jsp at http://spnego.sourceforge.net/ wich worked well,but I don't know what are the steps I have to follow for implement the solution. i.e. is enough to get the name of remote user? or I have to do something else for assure its identity and keep on the session of the current user?.

Comment: WAFFLE only works in windows machines OTOH spnego filter works on all platforms so you should choose http://spnego.sourceforge.net/

Comment: First, your Tomcat is ages old. Second, you are comparing apples with oranges. SPNEGO and WAFFLE are something completely different.

Comment: @Michael-O, Could you explain me please, why SPNEGO and WAFFLE are so differents?. I don´t understand, because i saw a post where both are considered as options for implement Java SSO, i.e. at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694975/choosing-kerberos-spnego-java-library-for-web-application-single-sign-on?rq=1.

Comment: SPNEGO is a mechnism, WAFFLE is a framework. Apples != oranges. You question has to be: Java SSO using WAFFLE with SPNEGO. If you need something fully integrated into Tomcat. Try my Tomcat module: http://sourceforge.net/p/tomcatspnegoad/code/35/tree/trunk/

Comment: @Michael-O. Thanks for your help. Could you correct me if I'm wrong?. I found information about WAFFLE Web Framework at http://waffle.codehaus.org/ and WAFFLE Windows Authentication Framework at https://github.com/dblock/waffle, and I think that they are different proyects. If they are different, which one you refer?

Comment: SPNEGO is not a framework, your title is still wrong.