# Auto-login using SPNEGO Web SSO

Tags: java, authentication, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego

We're planning to implement SSO using http://spnego.sourceforge.net/ on our web application. I've tried the sample projects in http://spnego.sourceforge.net/ and it worked well  (helloKDC.java and hello_spnego.jsp).

My question is, after authenticating the user successfully using SPNEGO, how can this user be login automatically to our web application? I know, that request.getRemoteUser() returns the client's windows username, but how about the client's windows password? If my understanding is correct, SPNEGO uses tokens instead of passwords?

Note: This question is somewhat similar to [Java SSO using SPNEGO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452580/java-sso-using-spnego) but unfortunately, no accepted answer on that.

Comment: Why you need password? Authentication by SPNEGO is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, SPNEGO uses tokens instead of passwords.  As to your first question, regarding how can user login automatically to web application, you have to create a Kerberos keytab and then copy it to your application server (and configure it to look at the keytab) in order to decrypt the SPNEGO token to "tell" who the user is.  Once a keytab is in place, logins to your web server using Kerberos SSO will then occur automatically.  Otherwise the token will just look like scrambled bits to your application and SSO authentication will fail.  Note you will never be able to see the password - there is no `request.getPassword()`.  In SPNEGO/Kerberos, the password is never revealed or exposed to anyone, not to the application server and not even to the Kerberos KDC itself, so it is impossible to grab the password in any way when using SPNEGO/Kerberos. That's one of the beauties of Kerberos.  For additional reference, you can read more from my technical article on how to create Kerberos keytabs here:  [Kerberos Keytabs – Explained](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36470.kerberos-keytabs-explained.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I realized that I don't need the password anymore as I will just autologin the user if the  request.getRemoteUser() is != null which means that the Spnego authentication is successful.